# How to return the corresponding number when the predication is true in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to return the factors of a number, and those factors should be in the given range. Like:

```
user=> (factors (range 1 10) 12)
(1 2 3 4 6)
```

I wrote some code, but they return true or false. My code is:

```
(defn factors [range num]
   (map #(= (mod num %) 0) range))
```

the test result:

```
user=> (factors (range 1 10) 12) 
(true true true true false true false false false)
```

How can I get the numbers `(1 2 3 4 6)` instead of true and false? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

Use [`filter`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter):

```
(defn factors [candidates num]
  (filter #(zero? (mod num %)) candidates))
```

Example:

```
(factors (range 1 10) 12)
;=> (1 2 3 4 6)
```

Comment: Got you! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd avoid using `range` as a name, as it is a relevant standard function. It is also misleading, as any sequence of numbers will do - it needn't be a range. For example, `(factors [2 8 9] 12) => (2)`. Perhaps `candidates` would fit.

Comment: @Thumbnail Agreed. I just used `range` because it was in the original question; I updated my answer to use `candidates` instead.